# Is it possible to fire a .then() block without a return value from a promise?

Tags: api, asynchronous, promise, callback

Curious issue I'm having dealing with some callback functions. I need to make a series of API calls that all return promises  then  I'm trying to take that data and map it to an array that exists on the global scope followed by a function to export the new data as a pdf - my issue is that the then() block is firing before the other function finishes and far before the first API call finshes.  `

```
 let fireWatson = async () => {
        let watsonClassifed = []
        let watsonCallIndex = 0;
        let returnedArr = []
        for (let i = 0; i < watsonData.length; i++) {
            let params = {
                classifierId: '***********',
                collection: watsonData[i]
            }
            naturalLanguageClassifier.classifyCollection(params,
                 function (err, response) {
                    if (err)
                        console.log('error:', err);
                    else
                        console.log("data returned")
                        console.log(response.result.collection)
                    watsonClassifed.push(response.result.collection);
                    console.log(watsonClassifed)
                })

    } 
} 

fireWatson(watsonData).then(res =>
        console.log("firing stupid callbback after data")
    )
```

I realize this function isnt actually returning anything but is it possible to still make use of a promise without a return value or is this the main issue im hitting?  Ideally - i want the then function to wait until the data is back - mapped to the global array and then outputted but this of course depends on proper synchronicity.

output:

```
[Done] exited with code=0 in 1.526 seconds

[Running] node "index.js"
firing stupid callbback 
data returned
all my sweet sweet data
```

Comment: Your main issue is that you are not waiting for `naturalLanguageClassifier.classifyCollection` to finish, which you'll need to [promisify](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572) first before you can use `await`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All functions in JavaScript have returns, it's just that they are **implicit** if you don't say `return` explicitly

It's always a bit tricky to mix promises with callbacks. Here is a way you can `fireWatson` without using any utilities.

```js
let fireWatson = async watsonData => Promise.all(watsonData.map(collection => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  let params = {
    classifierId: '***********',
    collection: collection,
  }
  return naturalLanguageClassifier.classifyCollection(params, function(err, response) => {
    if (err) {
      reject(err)
    } else {
      resolve(response)
    }
  })
})))
```

Of course, you can simplify this tremendously using a [utility](https://github.rubico.land#map) I created

```js
const { map } = require('rubico')

let fireWatson = map(collection => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  let params = {
    classifierId: '***********',
    collection: watsonData[i]
  }
  return naturalLanguageClassifier.classifyCollection(params, function(err, response) => {
    if (err) {
      reject(err)
    } else {
      resolve(response)
    }
  })
}))
```

Comment: just for my clarification the then()  block fires because nothnig was returned right?

Comment: it's not quite right to say that nothing was returned; rather `Promise<undefined>` was returned in the example you posted. `Promise` because the function used the `async` keyword. The Promise would contain the desired array if you return the promises like in the example in my answer. I will update my answer to reflect this better

Comment: gotcha!  sitll unclear as to why the callback fires so quickly - does the undefined promise get returned right away?

Comment: ah, so the callback fires so quickly because if you do not return the Promise.all(watsonData.map(...)) it will not wait for all those promises to resolve.

Comment: pleasure is all mine

Answer (score 0):

turns out console.log was firing because every .then() block expects a function.

wrong:

```
 fireWatson(watsonData).then(res =>
            console.log("firing stupid callbback after data")
        )
```

right:

```
fireWatson(watsonData).then(()res =>
            console.log("firing stupid callbback after data")
        )
```